# Como criar funções no jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções

Gostaria de saber a maneira correta, seguindo as boas práticas, de criar funções no jQuery.

Já utilizei assim:

```javascript
var focusToEnd = function() {
    ...
}
```

E também assim:

```javascript
; (function($) {
    $.fn.focusToEnd = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var v = $(this).val();
            $(this).focus().val("").val(v);
        });
    };
```

Porém não sei, qual das duas maneiras é correta, ou se não tem diferença.

Comment: O que você quer exatamente? Criar uma função que possa ser chamada como `$('#seletor').minhaFuncao()`, ou que seja chamada independentemente, como em `minhaFuncao()`?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/

Comment: @bfavaretto ai tanto faz, eu quero saber apenas qual a boa prática utilizando jQuery.

Comment: Eu estava um dia desses meio sem rumo no js, até que achei este guia. Só para somar ao post, já que você falou de melhores práticas, talvez um bom estilo lhe caia bem também.

https://github.com/armoucar/javascript-style-guide

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## $.fn.extend

Para *estender* o jQuery (leia-se plugin) existe a função [jQuery.fn.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend).

Exemplo:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  alertar: function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      alert($(this).text());
    });
  },
  exibirNoConsole: function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  }
});

$('.comment').alertar(); // exibe os textos dos elementos com a classe '.comment' como alert
$('.comment').exibirNoConsole(); // mesmo do acima só que no console
```

Atente-se para não confundir com a função [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) que funciona para qualquer objeto. `$.fn.extend(funcoes)` é equivalente a `$.extend($.fn, funcoes)`.

## Quando *estender* o jQuery?

jQuery é uma biblioteca JavaScript que lhe oferece manipulação de documentos HTML (DOM), eventos, animação, ajax, métodos utilitários de JavaScript em geral, dentre outros.

Se a função que desenvolveu faz *sentido* estar junto a essa gama de funcionalidades considere *ligá-la* junto ao jQuery (via o método demonstrado acima). Pense na sua função como um [plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/).

## JavaScript != jQuery

Note que respondi como criar uma função no *jQuery* (a biblioteca) e não em *JavaScript* (a linguagem).

Em JavaScript é muito simples:

```js
function hello() {
  alert('Hello World');
}
```

Notei pela sua pergunta que houve uma certa confusão entre o que é uma função JavaScript e uma *função jQuery*. Não existem *funções jQuery*, são todas JavaScript no final das contas. O que é possível é atrelar uma função desenvolvida por você ao objeto jQuery (o famoso `$`).

Recomendo estudar o básico de JavaScript antes de utilizar alguma biblioteca (principalmente se extensa como o jQuery) para que você não misture os conceitos no aprendizado.

Comment: Sendo assim, basta criar quantas funções eu desejar dentro do escopo de `$.fn.extend({` ou tenho que iniciar vários `$.fn.extend({`, sendo um para cada função?

Comment: Você pode criar mais de uma função de uma só vez, como `$.fn.extend({ funcao1: function() { ... }, funcao2: function() { ... });`. Mas lembre de considerar se faz sentido criar a função junto ao jQuery.

Comment: porque, isso tem algum porém?

Comment: @PatrickMaciel Só faz sentido adicionar a jQuery.fn funções que manipulem os nós do DOM (coleção selecionada via jQuery e disponível na sua função como `this`). Isso está um pouco confuso na sua pergunta, não dá pra dizer se está claro para você ou não.

Answer (score 10):

O jQuery é somente uma biblioteca construída com JavaScript, e funções são uma funcionalidade da linguagem, não do jQuery.

Seus dois exemplos são maneiras válidas de se criar funções, e ainda existem outras maneiras. Enquanto maneiras de se criar funções, elas não são tão diferentes. Mas seu uso é, sim, bem diferente.

No primeiro caso, `var focusToEnd = function...` você está criando uma função e atribuindo à variável `focusToEnd`. A partir desse ponto, você pode chamar sua função com `focusToEnd()`.

No segundo caso, você está "pendurando" a função em `$.fn`, que é um objeto especial do jQuery utilizado como *prototype* de todos os objetos criados com `$('um_seletor_aqui')`. A função não poderá ser chamada com `focusToEnd()`, somente como método de um objeto jQuery – por exemplo, `$('um_seletor_aqui').focusToEnd()`.

No segundo caso, portanto, você está criando um plugin do jQuery. No primeiro, uma função comum.

Answer (score 2):

A sintaxe para criar uma função é:

```javascript
function nomeDaFuncao(){
     //conteúdo...
}
```

depois disso você pode chamar ela de várias formas...