# Como "concatenar" funções JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, funções

Como faz a lib jQuery? Exemplo:

$(elemento).text('meu texto');

Eu quero saber como se faz uma função como a `text()` em JavaScript puro, só para aprender a teoria. Quero saber como o elemento html é passado como parâmetro para a função `text()`, que faz o `innerText` no mesmo elemento encapsulado pela função `$()`.

Quero saber como a função `text()` reconhece em que elemento ela deve adicionar o texto apenas sendo juntada ao `$()` com um ponto `(.)`?

Eu só uso jQuery, mas minha vontade é aprender o JS puro a fundo.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81128/129, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14968/como-criar-um-plugin-para-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-jquery/14975?s=1|1.1881#14975, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/500/129,

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão que essa pergunta tem mais relação com a implementação do que com o encadeamento de método, que é o que tem na outra questão. Seria bom o autor ler a postagem indicada, e [edit] a postagem aqui explicando melhor os pontos de interesse que a de lá não cobram, de qq forma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isto chama-se [*fluent interface*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101) ou *method chaining*. Ou pelo menos é uma forma semelhante.

A técnica básica é retornar o próprio objeto que está sendo manipulado, o `this`. O retornar algo que possa ser manipulado por outra função que espera um objeto.

Você pode ver o [código fonte do exemplo que usou](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.text). E o [código fonte do seletor](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=$) (vai acompanhando nos *links* o resto do código). No seletor verá que retorna `this` que será usado como argumento para a função `text()`.

Se quiser criar funções que se comuniquem especificamente com jQuery tem que seguir alguns protocolos. Tem alguns *links* no comentário do Sergio (na pergunta) que mostram como.

[Artigo em inglês sobre o assunto](https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html).

Comment: Além disso, o jQuery guarda os elementos selecionados na própria referência, sequencialmente, por exemplo: `this[0] = algumElementoDOMWindowEtc, this[1] = outroElementoEtc` (por acaso está correto afirmar isso?), exatamente como uma coleção, instanciada pela interface do jQuery.